# Using a Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

[image]

Hi, I'm really unsure of how to do this problem. Does anyone with expertise in Machine Learning know how to do this problem?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blog.aylien.com/naive-bayes-for-dummies-a-simple-explanation/) explains the concept of Naive Bayes classifier.
A "naiveness" in NBC is an assumption of independence of variables. For example, you can assume that Study outcome does not depend on Neighbor being home. This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212240/the-difference-between-the-bayes-classifier-and-the-naive-bayes-classifier) explains it. So for the first question

$P(Happy) = P(W=Good) \cdot P(S=Pass) \cdot P(N=Out)$

For the second this assumption does not hold, and

$P(Happy) = P(W=Good) \cdot P(S=Pass|N=Out)$

Of course, relationships might be more complicated, as Neighbor can go out only when it is good weather.